# How can I use my Ipython notebook code and output to within Latex (specifically in the Lyx GUI)

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook, lyx, reproducible-research

I have an Ipython notebook here and want to use it within the Lyx GUI so I can make a Latex document

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/decisionstats/4142e98375445c5e4174

```
import pandas as pd #importing packages
import os as os
#pd.describe_option() #describe options for customizing
#pd.get_option("display.memory_usage")#setting some options
os.getcwd() #current working directory
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to convert your Notebook into tex code? This can be done from the commandline as follows:

```
ipython nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to latex
```

You can read more about this [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/notebook/nbconvert.html)